# What is best way for object null and empty check?

Tags: c#

I have code as below in C#:

```
If  (this._university != Null and this._university.department !=null &&
     this._university.department.class !=null && 
     this._university.department.class.student != null && 
     this._university.department.class.student.name != null &&
     this._university.department.class.student.name.firstname != null &&
     this._university.department.class.student.name.firstname !=String.empty)

{
   // selecting first letter of Firstname
   var F_firstname = this._university.department.class.student.name.firstname[0].tostring();
}
```

But the code looks very bad for checking null object.Do we have better way for null check for objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using one of the later C# versions. Maybe this looks better with *Null-conditional Operators*. However, it is an unusual bit of code anyway and might point to the need to refactor a little.

```
var firstName = this._university?.department?.class?.student?.name?.firstname;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{
   ...
}
```

---

**Further Reading**

[Null-conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null before performing a
>   member access (?.) or index (?[]) operation; returns null if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to null.

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.